Troubleshooting Kodein dependency injection NullPointerException
I decided to switch from Koin to Kodein (because it supports Wash)
And it didn’t work out for me... I scoured all the documentation, the entire Internet (sort of), but I still couldn’t find what I did wrong. Can you show me or point your finger where?
I'll explain what the problem is:

Kodein.kt
val kodein = DI {

    lazy {

        import(platformModule) // driver implementation
        import(databaseModule)
        import(useCasesModule)
        import(repositoryModule)
        import(settingsModule)
        import(dispatcherModule)
    }

}

val useCasesModule = DI.Module(name = "useCasesModule") {

    // Team
    bindSingletonOf(::AddTeamUseCase)
    bindSingletonOf(::GetTeamsUseCase)
    bindSingletonOf(::GetTeamUseCase)
    bindSingletonOf(::DeleteTeamUseCase)
    bindSingletonOf(::TeamUseCases)

}

val repositoryModule = DI.Module(name = "repositoryModule") {

    bindSingleton { TeamRepositoryImpl(di) }

//    delegate<TeamRepository>().to<TeamRepositoryImpl>()


}

val databaseModule = DI.Module(name = "databaseModule") {
    bindSingletonOf(::createDatabase)

    bindProviderOf(::TeamDao)
    
    delegate<ITeamDao>().to<TeamDao>()
}

val settingsModule = DI.Module(name = "settingsModule") {
    delegate<MultiplatformSettings>().to<MultiplatformSettingsImpl>()

    bindSingleton("settings") { Settings() }
    bindSingleton("multisettings") { MultiplatformSettingsImpl(instance("settings")) }
}

val dispatcherModule = DI.Module(name = "dispatcherModule") {
//    bindProvider { rDispatchers.main }
}


main.kt for desktop
fun main() {


    val lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry()
    application {
        withDI(
            kodein
        ) {

            val root = DefaultRootComponent(DefaultComponentContext(lifecycle), di = localDI())
            val windowState = rememberWindowState()
            LifecycleController(lifecycle, windowState)


            Window(
                title = stringResource(MR.strings.app),
                state = windowState,
                onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication
            ) {
                RootContent(root)
            }
        }
    }
}

TeamUseCases.kt
data class TeamUseCases(
   val add: AddTeamUseCase,
   val get: GetTeamUseCase,
   val gets: GetTeamsUseCase,
   val delete: DeleteTeamUseCase,
)


class AddTeamUseCase(private val repository: TeamRepository) {


  suspend operator fun invoke(team: Team): Result<Long> =   
        repository.insertTeam(team)
 }

.....


In the Repository and in the Dao something like:
class TeamRepositoryImpl(override val di: DI) : TeamRepository, DIAware {

    private val dao by di.instance<ITeamDao>()

    .......
}


class TeamDao(override val di: DI) : ITeamDao, DIAware {
      private val database: AppDatabase by di.instance()

      .....
}

Well, “favorite” mistakes, where would we be without them?

 Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1" Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2" org.kodein.di.DI$NotFoundException: No binding found for TeamUseCases on context MainStoreFactory


Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@62517d1, Dispatchers.Default]
Exception in thread "main" org.kodein.di.DI$NotFoundException: No binding found for MultiplatformSettings on context DefaultRootComponent

But if you run outside the lazy tag
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.kodein.di.internal.DIBuilderImpl.import, parameter module

And yes, MainStore is from mvi-kotlin and decompose: MainComponent
class DefaultMainComponent(
    componentContext: ComponentContext,
    storeFactory: StoreFactory = DefaultStoreFactory(),
    override val di: DI,
) : MainComponent, DIAware, ComponentContext by componentContext {


    private val store =
        instanceKeeper.getStore {
            MainStoreFactory(
                storeFactory = storeFactory,
                di = di
                ).create()
        }
}

And it’s also important to take into account that the code worked with Koin
If I'm being too dumb somewhere, I'm sorry.
